# crush + direct object + resultative adjective

Tags: verbs, collocations, verb-pattern, resultative

I'd like to know whether the verb **crush** can take a direct object and a resultative adjective. Is the following correct?

> The rock crushed the driver dead/flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The rock crushed the driver flat.

That one works.

"Crushed dead" doesn't works so well; one would say

> The rock crushed the driver to death.